# Cannot wrap simple class defined in header file

Tags: c++, swig

I am stuck in the beginning stages of wrapping a .so file with csharp. However if I try to create a wrapper using one of the provided h files that contains a class then I get an error. I think it is because of `__attribute__ ((visibility ("default") ))` but I cant figure it out. Has anyone ever done this before?

I have a class defined in Test.h shown below:

```
class Test
{
  public:
    __attribute__ ((visibility ("default") )) Test();
    __attribute__ ((visibility ("default") )) ~Test();
};
```

I defined a interface file, which as you woul imagine is also very simple.

```
%module Test

%{
#include "Test.h"
%}


/* Let's just grab the original header file here */
%include "Test.h"
```

When I execute the command `swig -c++ -csharp -v test.i` I get the error message:

```
Test.h:4: Error: Syntax error in input(3).
```

Comment: is that o windows or Linux?

Comment: I am running linux

Comment: does swig understand `__attribute__`? the mailing lists seems to suggest you have to macro it out for the swig pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWIG doesn't know anything about `__attribute__`. You'll need to wrap it with this:

```
%module Test

%{
#include "Test.h"
%}

#define __attribute__(x) 

/* Let's just grab the original header file here */
%include "Test.h"
```